# I can't wish for someone to die, how to get around this rule?

Tags: magic

A genie gives you the ability to make any wish possible with a few rules :

1. no time travel
2. no destruction of the universe
3. not causing the death of anyone
4. not wishing for others to do whatever you want
5. ⅛ of your remaining lifetime is lost after making the wish.

Given you need someone to die, how do you accomplish this at 100% certainty given you paid with your own lifetime and failure is not an option?

Comment: This seems too easy "I wish their head explodes". How indirect must the cause of death be to avoid 3?

Comment: "magic" is tricky. Some interpretation of "not causing the death of anyone" would allow you to wish for someone to be transported at 20.000 meters high and let gravity/cold/hypoxia do the killing, some other interpretation would not allow for it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Blueprint. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. The question you have asked here, however, is a matter of story, or the specific actions of a character needed to advance a plot. We would be happy to help refine the rules of your genie, as that is a worldbuilding question, but addressing how those rules are implemented/evaded is an issue for you, the author, to resolve and is likely to lead to this question being put on hold.

Comment: I wish a hungry polar bear and the person to be alone together.

Comment: Might wanna add "No wishing for extra lifespan" in there my friend.

Comment: If you are looking for specific story solutions, then the sneaky thing to do is phrase your question to be broader "People in my world do X under restriction Y. How?" rather than "I need to do X".

Comment: Another question. Do you need the target to be really, most sincerely dead,  or is "functionally equivalent to dead such that nobody is going to know he's still alive" acceptable?

Comment: "I wish [target] gets teleported to the deepest point of the Mariana Trench". "I wish [target] turns into a  slug", then throw salt on it. "I wish [target] becomes infected with every retroviral disease existent on earth". "I wish [target]'s blood turns into pure water". There are so many things you can wish that will cause [target]'s death. Then use your second wish to wish to be able to have your remaining lifespan increased by  a century. You also still have one wish left to wish to become an omnipotent, omniscient being unbound by the genie's rules. This question  is a bit too broad.

Comment: So, can one wish for the position of unlimited power over the World, then? Once this wish is granted, getting rid of anyone would be a cakewalk.

Comment: There is no solution by definition. You want to make a wish so that someone die, without causing their death.

Comment: How about wishing that the person will be transported to a distant planet with an all powerful, just, and minding reading society which will quickly read the person's mind, decide how good or evil they are, and reward or punish them exactly as they deserve?.    If they deserve to die they will die, if they don't deserve to die you will not have murdered them.  You can also specify that the person will be removed from this planet in a way that convinces everyone that they died or were killed, in case you want society to think they are dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I wish Person X was teleported 5 feet in front of me with a whole piece of dried concrete at least 6 inches thick covering his whole body except for his head, displacing the air as he did so to avoid any kind of explosion when he teleports in."

Fairly straightforward, though I'm sure I'm going to get a whole comments section full of people explaining all the loopholes. However, as you are not time traveling, causing the death of the universe, killing anyone, or causing Person X to do what you want (because you aren't restricting his movements, the concrete is), this seems reasonable. If, for some reason, teleporting him isn't viable because it violates Rule 4, then just teleport to him instead.

At this point, Person X is trapped within 5 feet of you with his head fully exposed for you to kill him. I'd recommend a gun, but a knife will work. Or a hammer. (Really, a lot of things.) Once that is done, just wish all the evidence away and then wish for your life to be double to regain all that spent life and then some.

Comment: +1 for thoughtfully displacing the air.

Answer (score 8):

So extending my own lifespan isn't against the rules?

"I wish all of the target's remaining lifespan, except one day/hour/minute/second (choose as the wisher sees fit), was transferred to me."

I have not killed the target, I've only moved up the scheduled timeline of his death. Que sera, sera.

Answer (score 4):

**Murder**

Murder them and then, "I wish the court finds me not guilty."

Comment: How about wishing that the person will be transported to a distant planet with an all powerful, just, and minding reading society which will quickly read the person's mind, decide how good or evil they are, and reward or punish them exactly as they deserve?.  s